# Error on conversion System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to to create a custom model binder, that can parse the incoming request properly. The incoming request are in the form.

```
https://localhost:5001/api/hotel?filter=name~contains~'hotel'&page=1&pageSize=5
```

In controller I have used the model binder as:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<DataSourceResult> GetHotel([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(GridDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
{
```

`GridDataSourceRequestModelBinder` looks like:

```
public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(DataSourceRequest))
    {
        return;
    }
    var request = CreateDataSourceRequest(bindingContext.ModelMetadata, bindingContext.ValueProvider, bindingContext.ModelName);

    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(request);
}
```

`DataSourceRequest` request

```
public class DataSourceRequest
{
    public DataSourceRequest();

    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public IList<SortDescriptor> Sorts { get; set; }
    public IList<IFilterDescriptor> Filters { get; set; }
    public IList<GroupDescriptor> Groups { get; set; }
    public IList<AggregateDescriptor> Aggregates { get; set; }
}
```

CreateDataSourceRequest method:

```
public static DataSourceRequest CreateDataSourceRequest(ModelMetadata modelMetadata, IValueProvider valueProvider, string modelName)
{
    var request = new DataSourceRequest();

    TryGetValue(modelMetadata, valueProvider, modelName, DataSourceRequestUrlParameters.Page, (int currentPage) => request.Page = currentPage);

    TryGetValue(modelMetadata, valueProvider, modelName, DataSourceRequestUrlParameters.PageSize, (int pageSize) => request.PageSize = pageSize);

    TryGetValue(modelMetadata, valueProvider, modelName, DataSourceRequestUrlParameters.Filter, (string filter) =>
        request.Filters = FilterDescriptorFactory.Create(filter)
    );

    return request;
}
```

In the `TryGetValue` method I have the following code.

```
private static void TryGetValue<T>(ModelMetadata modelMetadata, IValueProvider valueProvider, string modelName, string key, Action<T> action)
{
    if (modelMetadata.BinderModelName.HasValue())
    {
        key = modelName + "-" + key;
    }

    var value = valueProvider.GetValue(key);
    if (value.FirstValue != null)
    {
        //Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

        var convertedValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertTo(value, typeof(T));

        if (convertedValue != null)
        {
            action((T)convertedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Here while converting the typeof(T) in the following code,

```
var convertedValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertTo(value, typeof(T));
```

I am getting the error as:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
```

What am I missing on the conversion of the value to type (T)?

Additional Class:

```
public static class DataSourceRequestUrlParameters
{
    public static string Aggregates { get; set; }
    public static string Filter { get; set; }
    public static string Page { get; set; }
    public static string PageSize { get; set; }
    public static string Sort { get; set; }
    public static string Group { get; set; }
    public static string Mode { get; set; }

    public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(string prefix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to convert the value which is a type of `IValueProvider` so it was giving me a error.

So, instead of that I have to use, `value.FirstValue`.

now it becomes:

```
var convertedValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertTo(value.FirstValue, typeof(T));
```

Comment: Once you replaced with `value.FirstValue` it should your error right?

Comment: error gone. after I replace with `value.FirstValue`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Glad to hear that you have successfully resolved your error.

Comment: But there used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.valueproviderresultextensions.convertto?view=aspnetcore-1.1 to convert the ValueProviderResult to Type T, but it is removed in the later version. I am looking for the similar alternative. Is there any?

Comment: As per your scenario, you have to pass your type, this is what I know.